# Can you call a before_filter from another before_filter in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter

Is it possible to call a before_filter from another? The reason I ask is because I have two similar before_filters, but one has an extra condition that could still let it be true. So, if the first before_filter is true than the second one is true as well, but if the first is false another condition is checked and then decided if it's true or false.

Comment: Why not just combine the two filters into a single method, replacing them with one filter?

Comment: Because one of the filters is a special edge case, persay, and only called from one controller action, while the other is called from many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct that filters are just methods, so to answer your question:

Yes, it is possible to call filters from other filter.

BUT beware that you should not render or redirect twice, otherwise you will receive a `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError`. Thus if one of the filters is rendering you should not call the other filter.

Use boolean return values to manage this.

Answer (score 0):

You can. A before_filter is just a trigger that invokes a regular method. That method can invoke any other method, even methods invoked by other before_filters.

Comment: The caveat is that a filter will often render or redirect. You must take care of this.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to combine the methods I you could do something like this.

```
before_filter :filter_method

def filter_method
 if method_one == true
  method_two
 end
end

def method_one
 # stuff here
end

def method_two
 # stuff here
end
```